# Yarn start command on terminal throwing 'Package subpath not defined' error. How can I resolve this?

Tags: terminal, yarn-v2, yarn-lock.json

When I input `yarn start` on my terminal I get this error;

```
mac@Chris-MacBook-Pro IPFS-ethereum % yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:575
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/mac/Documents/IPFS-ethereum/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:261:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:591:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:643:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Documents/IPFS-ethereum/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.1.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How do I fix it?